# Taking more storage in minio master node

Tags: data-warehouse, minio

I have 4 node Minio cluster setup on production environment. It has been running more than 2 years without any major issues. it stores more than 1.5 TB in each server.
Node -4 which is the master node has been taking more storage [30 GB more compare with other nodes] for almost 1 month.
We can't find out any mojor issue while investigating this issue. Can someone help us with some hits here please.

Comment: How is that related to Scala? Also I believe this is more a question for ServerFault rather than SO.

Comment: This is not related to Scala , I did remove the tag.